# Embedding YouTube to Facebook og:meta

Tags: facebook, youtube

I have added all my og:meta tags correctly and the Facebook debugger scrapes correctly. The only problem I have is that the thumbnail for the video is cropped when shared from our website, but perfect if shared from YouTube.

Our META:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="259859127379080">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.zanews.co.za/others/testing-one-two-three/2012/01/30/">
<meta property="og:title" content="Testing One Two Three  |  ZANews">
<meta property="og:description" content="Testing One Two Three">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/CBJxtlHDcfU/hqdefault.jpg">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/CBJxtlHDcfU?version=3&autohide=1">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="398">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="224">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ZA News | Let's get it on!">
```

And the Result:
[image: post from the website]

YouTube's META:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="87741124305">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBJxtlHDcfU">
  <meta property="og:title" content="ZANEWS: Ask The Coach">
  <meta property="og:description" content="So a lot of people ask me, they say Pieter, rugby is confusing, it&#39;s so hard to understand. I say, no, what is hard to understand is when I speak English.">
  <meta property="og:type" content="video">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/CBJxtlHDcfU/hqdefault.jpg">
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/CBJxtlHDcfU?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
  <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <meta property="og:video:width" content="398">
  <meta property="og:video:height" content="224">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
```

And the Result:
[post from youtube http://www.zanews.co.za/wp-content/uploads/zanews2.JPG](http://www.zanews.co.za/wp-content/uploads/zanews2.JPG)

So: for a few minor differences (content related) they are pretty much the same but the post thumbnail images differ quite a bit.

I have also picked up in the linter when I debug the website URL(http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zanews.co.za%2Fothers%2Ftesting-one-two-three%2F2012%2F01%2F30%2F) the linter initially shows:

```
 {
     "url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/CBJxtlHDcfU?version=3&autohide=1",
     "type": "application\/x-shockwave-flash",
     "width": 398,
     "height": 224
 }
```

but when I pass it through the graph (http://graph.facebook.com/10150521224263339) I get:

```
  {
     "url": "http://www.youtube.com/e/CBJxtlHDcfU",
     "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
     "width": 398,
     "height": 224
  }
```

Been driving me mad - so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this makes any sense, what worked from me though is changing the "http://i4.ytimg.com" part from og:image url to "https://img.youtube.com"